# HLS Streaming in native browser

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, streaming

I've read in numerous sites that Android has supported HLS streaming since 3.0.

However, I've been unsuccessful in getting any HLS stream to play back as it should on devices I've tested.

HTC OneX running 4.0.x
Samsung Galaxy Nexus 4.1.x

I can't find any definitive answers on true HLS support in Android. Does anyone have a good answer here or point me to an article describing the limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to play in a browser?  I have found that is not supported but playing in an Android app using the native MediaPlayer should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm specifically asking about a native android browser. But since I asked this question, it seems to be supported now, both in native and in Chrome on Android 4.4